# Can I pray Qasr if I began praying regularly again?

Tags: halal-haram

so this is a question that I hope is not too complicated to answer.

Currently, I have been living abroad for three months at a place that does not belong to me but instead to friends of our family who have extended a hand to allow us to stay with them for our duration abroad.

For about a month and a half, I was praying Qasr Salat when on one occasion I was praying together with my father when we prayed the entire four Ra'ka's instead of two.

Ever since then, I've prayed normally even though, as previously mentioned the place that we are currently living in does not belong to us.

This has caused me, on numerous occasions, many inconveniences as sometimes we have to travel long trips to our nearest city (70+ miles away) and there aren't many mosques near us which has made it very easy for me to miss salah which would have otherwise never happened had I still been praying qasr.

Now my dilemma is that if I prayed normally in my current location then how could I return to praying Qasr again? I fear that I would be making a big mistake. Could I please have an answer to this problem? Thank you.